# Is there any way to reset the `httpd.conf` in CentOS to the original/default version?

Tags: centos-6, httpd

I was learning server installation by creating a web server in VMware, I don’t know what changes I made to `httpd.conf`.

Is there any way to reset all the configuration for `httpd.conf` to default?

Command used:

1. `vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
2. Updated `ServerName` to `localhost`
3. `service httpd restart`
4. `chkconfig httpd on`
5. `service httpd restart`

Comment: Restore from the backup copy you made before editing?

Comment: It sounds like might not have a back up.  What you could do is copy the `httpd.conf` that you have now and back it up. Delete the original and run `sudo apt-get reinstall httpd`. Go back and see if it created a new `.conf`, if so then it should be fixed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Shorter answer:

You could simply erase or move the `httpd.conf` file you adjusted and then run the following command and it will be reinstalled:

```
yum reinstall httpd
```

#### Longer answer:

But if you want to be a bit more methodical about it, you could [follow the ideas and concepts shown on this page](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2012/03/26/restore-original-configuration-files-from-rpm-packages/).

First, check what package installed `httpd.conf` by running this command:

```
rpm -qf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Of course that would show you that the `httpd` package installed it, but it will also give you additional version info. So now you can verify what was changed between the initial install from the RPM to when you adjusted it by verifying it with RPM like this:

```
rpm -V httpd
```

Output would most likely show you `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` preceded by some verification info which should look like this:

```
S.5....T.  c /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

That can be translated as the `S`ize was changed, the MD`5` checksum is different and the `T`ime is different. More details on what those one letter codes mean are below:

```
S file Size differs
M Mode differs (includes permissions and file type)
5 MD5 sum differs
D Device major/minor number mismatch
L readLink(2) path mismatch
U User ownership differs
G Group ownership differs
T mTime differs
P caPabilities differ
```

But the long and short of it is you will be able to see exactly what files from the `httpd` package had changed and for what reason. Which could be useful to know if you happened to add or changed any file other than `httpd.conf` and it slipped your mind.

Now you *might* want to remove the current `httpd.conf` like this:

```
sudo rm /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

But I would recommend keeping a copy of it for reference like this:

```
sudo mv /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ~/httpd.conf.modified
```

That would move `httpd.conf` to your home directory and rename it `httpd.conf.modified`.

Finally, you can reinstall `httpd` like this:

```
yum reinstall httpd
```

And your Apache `httpd.conf` config file should be back to it’s original, untouched RPM state.

Answer (score 4):

[@Giacomo1968's answer](https://superuser.com/a/897912/167207) is great but to be more explicit:

`yum reinstall httpd` will only restore *missing* files, not the changed configs. By moving/removing the old configuration file first, that allowed `yum reinstall` to restore the file.

Alternatively, you could use the method shown here:
[How to force `yum reinstall` to overwrite changed files in a `/var` sub-directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/1411940/how-to-force-yum-reinstall-to-overwrite-changed-files-in-a-var-sub-director)